# Error during parsing with protobuf in Java and C++ Application

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

I try to use protobuf for message exchange between two java applications (client and server).
The protobuf code is completely developed in C++ (the TLS client/server logic too). The 'raw' protobuf classes are wrapped by the C++ code in a simple C++ class which is just delegating the method calls to the original protobuf code. This C++ Wrapper is again wrapped for Java with SWIG.*

I fill the protobuf in the java client with the following calls:

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.setUser("test");
msg.setPassword("pwd");
```

which will delegate the information to the C++ Wrapper and from there to protbuf. The data is transmitted correctly, but if I try to parse the serialized data on the java server side the parsing fails:

```
Message message = new Message();
boolean p = message.parse(data); // will call ParseFromString(data); on C++  layer with try catch
```

However on the c++ layer of the server application it works fine.

I compared the 'raw' protobuf data on C++ and Java layer (server side) and noticed that they look different:

```
//c++
test�pwd
//java
testÿpwd
```

The length information is not shown on stackoverflow, but they are the same on java and c++.

What could cause this difference? Is there some problem with the encoding?

(*) I decided to go this extra step because in this case all the protobuf logic is hiden for SWIG.

Note: I only work with strings and use `parseFromString` and `SerializeAsString` from C++. Java does not call this methods directly.

**EDIT:**
Message has two more fields 'bool success' and 'string name'. If I remove them both, the parsing works (the symbol between user and pwd was gone). Why?

```
message Message{  
    required string user = 1;
    optional string pwd = 2;
    //optional string name = 3; 
    //optional bool success = 4;    
}
```

**EDIT**
It was indeed a problem with Java String encoding. Also see my other related question [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164247/strange-behaviour-in-protobuf-with-long-strings)

Comment: what are the actual bytes of the "raw" data?  can you show your java server parsing code?

Comment: the actual bytes are shown above, they differ at one position. I will add the code from java server side.

Comment: how do they differ, what are the actual byte values (as numbers)?

Comment: maybe a dumb question from my side but: how can I see the "byte values"?

Comment: treat each "char" as an int.  `int i = 0xFF & c`

Comment: what is "data" in your example code?  the more _relevant_ information you provide, the easier it is for someone to help you...

Comment: the binary data, which means: the result of SerializeAsString on client side which was transmitted over TLS.  Does that int conversion work in Java and C++?

Comment: is "data" a byte[]?  is it a String?  please re-read the end of my previous comment.  i can't read your code on your computer or your mind, i can only read your post.

Comment: I wrote that I only use string, no byte[] no char*. I'm woriking on the byte value output. soon to come.

Comment: if you are only using String, are you ensuring that your java and c++ code are both using the same character encoding?

Comment: I also suspected that this might cause the problem (that's why I asked if it could be an encoding problem). How can I ensure that the encoding is the same?

Comment: no idea, you haven't shown any of the relevant code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the protobuf java api, it always uses "byte[]" for serialized data.  i suspect you are having problems because java Strings are not the same as c++ strings.  I would use byte[] exclusively for the data in Java.